# Find surface area of sphere using integration of differential area element

Tags: integration

I find a problem when i try to integrate to find the surface area of a sphere of radius $r$. I assume a differential area element in spherical coordinates,

$$dA = rd\psi\cdot rd\theta$$
$$=r^2d\phi d\theta$$
$$A=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0}r^2d\phi d\theta$$
$$=4\pi^2r^2$$

Why is this wrong? I am aware that a $\sin\theta$ or $\sin\phi$ comes into play but I do not know how to incorporate this into the expression for $dA$. Could someone help me explain why this factor of $\sin\theta$ appears?

Comment: Which is your azimuthal angle (measured from $\hat{x}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigorous way to do it is with the Jacobian. For an informal idea, this picture may help (sorry for the low quality and bad drawing):

[image]

If we consider the sides of a "small" tangential square, we can easily see that the height (vertical component) is $r \Delta \theta$, but to find the horizontal component we must use the distance from the z-axis ($r \sin\theta$), not just $r$, which results in $r \sin \theta \Delta \phi$.

The area is therefore $width \cdot height = r^2 \sin \theta \Delta \theta \Delta \phi$.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the correct area element.  The correct area element incorporates also $\sin\phi$: $$r^2\sin\phi \,d\phi \, d\theta.$$ Here $\phi$ is the angle with the positive $z$-axis. If you parametrize the sphere using the generating curve $(\sin \phi, \cos\phi)$, you will get the extra factor as the determinant of the Jacobian.

Comment: Could you explain why this factor of $\sin \phi$ appears? Thank you.

Comment: You need to learn more about the Jacobian. See http://booksite.elsevier.com/andrilli/elementary/content/jacobian.pdf. In particular page 8 is what you are looking for.